# Symfony2 - Count row / Joined Tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, count

I'm a begginer in Symfony2...

I have a table `"TUTORIEL"` and an other table `'Groupe_de_categories'` linked by `'id_groupe_categorie'`

TABLE `Tutoriels` :
[image: TABLE 'TUTORIEL']

TABLE `Groupe_de_categories`
[image: TABLE 'Groupe_de_categories']

I need to count for each `"titre_categorie_nv1"` (here in my example `'Maison'`, `'Art&Loisir'`, `'Enseignement'`...) how many `"TUTORIEL"` I have where `"tutoriel_controle"` = `'no'`

[image: tuto]
[image: categories]

Before to use Synfony2, I hade this code in PHP (works nice):

```
<?php

$query_nb_cat = "SELECT CATEGORIE, COUNT(*) 
    FROM Tutoriels 
    INNER JOIN Groupe_de_categories 
    ON TUTORIEL.id_groupe_categorie = Groupe_de_categories.id_groupe_categorie 
    WHERE tutoriel_controle='no' 
    GROUP BY CATEGORIE_TITLE";

$nb_cat = mysqli_query($BDD_connect, $query_nb_cat)or die(log_mysql($query_nb_cat));
    $row_nb_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nb_cat);
do {
    $tableau_nb_cat[]=array(
        'titre_cat_nv1'=>$row_nb_cat['titre_categorie_nv1'],
        'compte_cat_nv1'=>$row_nb_cat['COUNT(*)'],
    );
} while ($row_nb_cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($nb_cat));

$val_cat=array(
    'valeur_retour'=>$tableau_nb_cat
);
mysqli_free_result($nb_cat);

mysqli_close($BDD_connect);
?>
```

The result was something like that :

Maison => 3

Art&Loisir => 9

Enseignement => 14

...

How can I do this with Symfony2 ?

Here is my ORM :

Tutoriel `'Video2LearnBddBundle:Tutoriels'`:

```
Tutoriels
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_tutoriel", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idTutoriel;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=70, nullable=false)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=false)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $dateCreation = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre_de_vues", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nombreDeVues;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="FAQs", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $faqs;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="exclusivite", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $exclusivite;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="eligible_promotion", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $eligiblePromotion;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="info_moderateur", type="string", length=300, nullable=true)
     */
    private $infoModerateur;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tutoriel_controle", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $tutorielControle = 'non';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="niveau_choix_categorie_autre", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $niveauChoixCategorieAutre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="categorie_autre", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $categorieAutre;

    /**
     * @var \GroupeDeCategories
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GroupeDeCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_groupe_categorie", referencedColumnName="id_groupe_categorie")
     * })
     */
    private $idGroupeCategorie;

    /**
     * @var \Membres
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Membres")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_membre", referencedColumnName="id_membre")
     * })
     */
    private $idMembre;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MotsCles", inversedBy="idTutoriel")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="mots_cles_et_tutoriels",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_tutoriel", referencedColumnName="id_tutoriel")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="mots_cles", referencedColumnName="mots_cles")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $motsCles;
```

Groupe_de_categorie `GroupeDeCategories`:

```
<?php

namespace Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * GroupeDeCategories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Groupe_de_categories", indexes={
 *      @ORM\Index(name="fk_Groupe_de_categories_Categories_nv11_idx", columns={"titre_categorie_nv1"}), 
 *      @ORM\Index(name="fk_Groupe_de_categories_Categories_nv21_idx", columns={"titre_categorie_nv2"}), 
 *      @ORM\Index(name="fk_Groupe_de_categories_Categories_nv31_idx", columns={"titre_categorie_nv3"}), 
 *      @ORM\Index(name="fk_Groupe_de_categories_Categories_nv41_idx", columns={"titre_categorie_nv4"}), 
 *      @ORM\Index(name="fk_Groupe_de_categories_Categories_nv51_idx", columns={"titre_categorie_nv5"})
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class GroupeDeCategories
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_groupe_categorie", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $idGroupeCategorie;

    /**
     * @var \CategoriesNv1
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Video2Learn\BddBundle\Entity\CategoriesNv1", inversedBy="GroupeDeCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="titre_categorie_nv1", referencedColumnName="titre_categorie_nv1")
     * })
     */
    private $titreCategorieNv1;

    /**
     * @var \CategoriesNv2
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoriesNv2")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="titre_categorie_nv2", referencedColumnName="titre_categorie_nv2")
     * })
     */
    private $titreCategorieNv2;


    /**
     * @var \CategoriesNv3
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoriesNv3")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="titre_categorie_nv3", referencedColumnName="titre_categorie_nv3")
     * })
     */
    private $titreCategorieNv3;

    /**
     * @var \CategoriesNv4
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoriesNv4")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="titre_categorie_nv4", referencedColumnName="titre_categorie_nv4")
     * })
     */
    private $titreCategorieNv4;

    /**
     * @var \CategoriesNv5
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CategoriesNv5")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="titre_categorie_nv5", referencedColumnName="titre_categorie_nv5")
     * })
     */
    private $titreCategorieNv5;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that :

```
public function updateAction($type_update) 
{
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $result = $request->isXmlHttpRequest();
    if ($result === true) {
        switch ($type_update) {
            case "compteur_menu":
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $result = $em->createQuery("
                SELECT TC.titreCategorieNv1, COUNT(TC.titreCategorieNv1) AS num  
                FROM Video2LearnBddBundle:Tutoriels T
                INNER JOIN T.idGroupeCategorie GC
                INNER JOIN GC.titreCategorieNv1 TC
                WHERE T.tutorielControle='non'
                GROUP BY TC.titreCategorieNv1"
                        )
                        ->getResult();
                $response = new Response();
                $response->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_OK);
                $response->setContent(json_encode($result));
                $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                return $response;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How come this could fix it, you did not use any Group By and you totally changed your query mentioned in your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `createQueryBuilder` in your repository, or you can use your current query as [NativeQuery](http://blog.xfloyd.net/?p=600) 
Here is a sample (I assume the name of your entities are `Tutoriels` and `GroupeDeCategories`)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Tutoriels')
   ->createQueryBuilder('T')
   ->join('T.idGroupeCategorie', 'GC')
   -->select('COUNT(GC.titreCategorieNv1) AS CT1')
   ->where("T.tutorielControle = 'no'")
   ->groupBy('GC.titreCategorieNv1')
   ->getQuery();
$result = $query->getScalarResult(); //This will return an array of the counts
```

In your entity I could not find `CATEGORIE_TITLE` to use in GroupBy and `CATEGORIE` to add in the selection; so I grouped them by `titreCategorieNv1`. You can add more fields for your select.
Maybe this link helps you more [Symfony CreateQueryBuilder](http://phpdox.de/demo/Symfony2/classes/Doctrine_DBAL_Query_QueryBuilder.xhtml)

Comment: It's work good :) thanks ! but how can I have this kind of return :
"Maison => 3"
"Art&Loisir => 9"
"Enseignement => 14"
Because with that, I have just the count... How to associate the name of the Categorie with the count ?

Comment: Like in my PHP example (do an array or something like that)

Answer (score -1):

You can do a repository (more infos here : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/book/doctrine.html )
And you could use Doctrine Query Language.

But I think your struture is wrong and it wold be better to have a category, this category has a parent category, ...

So you'll have for example a rootcatégory who has  childs named "Bricolage", "Sport", ... 
"Bricolage" would have, for exemple a category "Peinture" as child, and so on ;)